# Defaulted move members defined as deleted, when no special members defined?

Tags: c++

In a talk at Accu 2014, there is a slide which basically says:

If user declares no special member functions (constructors/destructors/`operator=`), then "Defaulted move members defined as deleted". Slide 21, [here](https://accu.org/content/conf2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf).

Yet, this simple program will print that move functions are called:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>

struct Foo {
    Foo() { printf("Foo()\n"); }
    Foo(const Foo &) { printf("Foo(const Foo &)\n"); }
    Foo(Foo &&) { printf("Foo(Foo &&)\n"); }
    ~Foo() { printf("~Foo()\n"); }

    Foo &operator=(const Foo &) { printf("Foo::operator=(const Foo &)\n"); return *this; }
    Foo &operator=(Foo &&) { printf("Foo::operator=(Foo &&)\n"); return *this; }
};

struct Baz {
    Foo f;
};

int main() {
    Baz b;
    Baz c(std::move(b));

    b = Baz();
}
```

Output:

```
Foo()
Foo(Foo &&)
Foo()
Foo::operator=(Foo &&)
~Foo()
~Foo()
~Foo()
```

In the program, `Baz` doesn't have any special functions, yet it seems that move functions are called, which is against the rule in the slide, as move functions should have been deleted.

Are the slides wrong? Do I misunderstand something? Have something changed in the standard regarding this (I've tried to compile with `-std=c++11/14/17`, same results)?

Comment: But you _do_ declare a move constructor: `Foo(Foo &&)`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: not in `Baz`.

Comment: It says that it "can mean" the member is deleted, not that it always does

Comment: @StoryTeller: the second bullet point doesn't say "can mean". It even says, "No, I'm not kidding".

Comment: @geza - It says how they behave *when* defined as deleted

Comment: @StoryTeller: here is the exact quote: "Defaulted move members defined as deleted, actually behave as not declared". To me, it means that defaulted move members defined as deleted.

Comment: @geza - Then I daresay you are not reading it as intended by the author.

Comment: @geza You missed the point. They are deleted **if they would have to do something illegal**. And the second point only explains how it behaves **if it has been deleted**.

Comment: @geza For this reading, it's missing an "are".

Comment: @Angew: yes, maybe I misunderstood it, because I'm not a native english speaker. And yeah, as you say, the comma should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misreading the slides. I will reproduce the entire text from that slide here:

> - “defaulted” can mean “deleted” if the defaulted special member would have to do something illegal, such as call another deleted function.
> - Defaulted move members defined as deleted, actually behave as not declared.
>
>   - No, I’m not kidding!

What it's saying: "If defaulted special member would have to do something illegal, it is defined as deleted. **If** a defaulted move member is defined as deleted, it actually behaves as if it was not declared at all."

Your interpretation missed the bolded **if**. It's not saying that move defaulted move members will always be deleted. It's saying that if a defaulted move member is deleted, it is considered not declared at all (C++11) or does not participate in overload resolution (C++14+), which is effectively the same as not existing. In other words, such classes will silently fall back to doing a copy when moved.

Comment: Thanks! I missed it, because it is not there. Then this sentence should have not been a separate bullet point.

Comment: @geza It's perfectly fine as a bullet point, IMO. I'd do it the same if I was writing that slide. However, the *comma* should not be there, and I can see how it can add confusion.